# How to disable Auto Layout in Xcode 5.1.1?

Tags: ios, xcode5, autolayout

It used to be possible to disable Auto Layout in the File Inspector, but I  running Xcode 5.1.1, and can't find how to disable it.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to disable it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option is still in the File Inspector on XCode 5.1.1.

Select the relevant view ---> Go to the File Inspector ---> Uncheck the "Use Auto Layout" option (it's in the "Interface Builder Document" section).

I double checked to see that I'm using the same version as you and the option is there. If you don't see it there, please add a screenshot of the File Inspector that you do see so that it may help with your issue.

Comment: Ah, I found it. I had it open to the main folder showing General Settings, but when I went to Storyboard view, it was there. Thank you!